# React AntD Form dynamic form automatically make list of fields, or remove add button after

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, antd

I am working on a react app on rails using AntD. I am trying to make a form.list that has thirty items with four fields each.

I was was able to make a form with dynamically added fields by adapting this [codesandbox example][1] It worked great (in my example code below I made it rooms), I can add a room one at a time and the button provides four fields to enter information on the room and that passes into my controller and saves.

The problem is I want it to automatically map 30 ones and have them blank, as opposed to adding one at a time and having it map to the ones that have been made.

Right now I just added a for loop so that when the button is clicked, it creates 30 items.

I would really like to know how to skip the add button and creating 30 with it, and just have it automatically populate thirty items with fields.

Or I would also be okay with after the button being pressed, some code causes it to disappear. I have searched all over and while it is easy to make a button get rid of itself in normal code, I can't figure out how to remove a form item from within the form. As far as I know I can't give it a state and manipulate it in the form like with visible false.

If anyone could help me figure out how to make a form.list automatically have 30 items, or how to make a button remove itself (or both) I would greatly appreciate it.

```
    <Form layout="horizontal" onFinish={onFinish} size="medium">
  <Form.Item name="building" label="Building">
    <Select>
      <Option>Building 1</Option>
      <Option>Building 2</Option>
    </Select>
  </Form.Item>
    <Form.List name="rooms">
      {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {fields.map((field, index) => (
              <Form.Item key={field.key} style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
                <Row gutter={8}>
                  <Col span={6} key={0}>
                    <Form.Item
                      name={[field.name, "room_type"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "room_type"]}
                    >
                      <Select style={{ marginRight: 8 }}>
                          <Select.Option key={item} value={item}>
                            {item}
                          </Select.Option>
                      </Select>
                    </Form.Item>
                  </Col>
                  <Col span={6} key={1}>
                    <Form.Item
                      name={[field.name, "square_feet"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "square_feet"]}
                    >
                        <Input />
                    </Form.Item>
                  </Col>
                  <Col span={6} key={2}>
                    <Form.Item
                      name={[field.name, "bedroom_num"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "bedroom_num"]}
                      labelCol={{ span: 12 }}
                    >
                      <InputNumber />
                    </Form.Item>
                  </Col>
                  <Col span={6} key={3}>
                    <Form.Item
                      name={[field.name, "bathroom_num"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "bathroom_num"]}
                    >
                      <Input />
                    </Form.Item>
                  </Col>
                  <Col span={2} key={4}>
                    <MinusCircleOutlined
                      className="dynamic-delete-button"
                      onClick={() => {
                        remove(field.name);
                      }}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Form.Item>
            ))}
            <Col span={22} key={2}>
              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                      add();
                    }
                  }}
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add unit number
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </Col>
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </Form.List>
  <Form.Item>
    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
      submit
    </Button>
  </Form.Item>
</Form>


  [1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-uhu2v?file=/index.js
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-nfth6?file=/index.js is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No I appreciate the idea but a button that creates 30 rows is what I have now. I am trying to create 30 rows without a button, or remove the button after it is clicked. Is there a way to use the setFields on load instead of in the button?

Comment: Yes, you can call `setFields` everywhere you want, I edited the example to call `setFields` when component loaded.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much. I was not using useForm() before but that seems to help.

Comment: So I have one other question, if I were to use a drop down to change a value in one the bulk created fields. How would I do that? I tried onChange={(value) => {
            alert(value)
            form.setFields([{ name: "fieldname", value: value }]);
          }}>

This didn't work, is it something like inclusions.fieldname?

Answer (score 1):

You can use initialValue prop to populate Form.List:

```
<Form.List name="rooms" initialValue={Array.from({length: 30}, () => ({}))}>
```